# Why does CUDA.rules have two identical command lines

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, cmd, cuda, build-rules

The commandline for CUDA.rules file is:

> echo [CompilerPath] [Keep]
>   [CInterleavedPTX] [ExtraNvccOptions]
>   [Arch] -ccbin
>   "$(VCInstallDir)bin"
>   [Emulation] [FastMath] [Defines]
>   -Xcompiler "/EHsc [Warning] /nologo [Optimization] /Zi
>   [RuntimeChecks] [Runtime] [TypeInfo]
>   [ExtraCppOptions]" [Include]
>   [MaxRegCount] [PtxAsOptionV]
>   [NvccCompilation]
>   "$(InputPath)"
>
> [CompilerPath] [Keep]
>   [CInterleavedPTX] [ExtraNvccOptions]
>   [Arch] -ccbin
>   "$(VCInstallDir)bin"
>   [Emulation] [FastMath] [Defines]
>   -Xcompiler "/EHsc [Warning] /nologo [Optimization] /Zi
>   [RuntimeChecks] [Runtime] [TypeInfo]
>   [ExtraCppOptions]" [Include]
>   [MaxRegCount] [ptxasoptionv]
>   [NvccCompilation]
>   "$(InputPath)""

I have put  in a line for clarity as it shows two command which are identical (as far as I can see), except the first one is preceded by "echo".  Does anyone know what the purpose of this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first only tells you what the command is going to be, the second actually performs the command.
`echo` is the dos command that displays text:

```
C:\>echo bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

Comment: I feel a little silly now, but it's odd as the echoing prevents successful compilation

Answer (score 1):

The first line will output the command line on the output window